# Create jenkins credentials via API on other Domain except GLOBAL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-cli, jenkins-api

As i explained on the Title have a piece of groovy script to create a credential (SSH key based) on jenkins master GLOBAL domain but i would like to know is there any way to create the same on other domain except GLOBAL.

Say for example have below list of domain:
global
test
test1
test2
test3

Want to create a credential on test2 domain...

Comment: Have you found an answer for this question? I'm trying to do the same thing but can't figure it out.